# Listar todos os dados de uma pesquisa

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Como listar todos os dados dessa consulta, eu só consigo mostrar a primeira linha mas quero consultar todas e mostrar elas.

```
public function gerarCardapio(){
        try{
            $cat = "M";
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM alimentos WHERE id_usuario = :idUser AND categoria = :cat AND quantidade >0 ";
            $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam('idUser', $_SESSION['user_id']);
            $stmt->bindParam('cat', $cat);
            $stmt->execute();//Executa o comano SQL
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo $stmt->rowCount();
        }catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No código, não vejo aonde você esta retornando ou imprimindo o resultado na tela, a não ser o número de linhas que foi retornado `echo $stmt->rowCount();`

Comment: A documentação é sua amiga, veja o exemplo #2: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#example-1058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como comentado pelo @Knautiluz, você deve utilizar o `while`.

```
# Apenas um exemplo de uso, pois não sei os nomes das colunas.
while($linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    printf("id_usuario: %s categoria: %s", $linha['id_usuario'], $linha['categoria']);
}
```

ficando assim seu método:

```
public function gerarCardapio(){
    try{
        $cat = "M";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM alimentos WHERE id_usuario = :idUser AND categoria = :cat AND quantidade >0 ";
        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':idUser', $_SESSION['user_id']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':cat', $cat);
        $stmt->execute();//Executa o comano SQL
        # Apenas um exemplo de uso, pois não sei os nomes das colunas.
        while($linha = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            printf("id_usuario: %s categoria: %s", $linha['id_usuario'], $linha['categoria']);
        }
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

> Você pode ver um exemplo básico em [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php_mysql_online.php)

Recomendo que leia na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.bindparam.php) como fazer a utilização da função *bindParam*.

#### Referências

- [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php)
- [while](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.while.php)

Answer (score 1):

Percebi que você está retornando o número de linhas do campo alimentos da tabela usando `echo $stmt->rowCount();`

Use `$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`,

E também use **:** no tratamento do **bindParam(:..., $....);**

```
public function gerarCardapio(){
  try{
    $cat = "M";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alimentos WHERE id_usuario = :idUser AND categoria = :cat AND quantidade > 0 ";
    $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':idUser', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cat', $cat);
    $stmt->execute();//Executa o comano SQL
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($result);
  }catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```